# Blazor Web App, ASP.NET Core Hosted. Windows Authentication Only Accepting Local Admin Accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have created a Blazor application with ASP.Net Core hosting.

I have edited the debug properties of the server solution and enabled Windows Authentication. When debugging the application in IISExpress, the browser immediately requests credentials. For some reason, it will only accept my domain account with local administration rights, and not my standard domain account that I am running VS2019 as, etc.

Using the User.Identity.Name property returns my correct DOMAIN\USERNAME for my domain account with local administrator privileges, so that aspect is working OK.

Been Googling for a while but I cannot find anything. Does anyone have any clue as to what is going on? VS2017 doesn't seem to have this problem - although the application I'm having this issue with is my first ASP.NET Core hosted application with Windows Authentication.